# Importing List of Excel Files (R Session Aborts)

Tags: r

I have a short chunk of code to import GC data from ~240 Excel Files. The code worked the last time I opened the document, but now when I try to run the chunk, my R Session Aborts without throwing an error message.

UPDATE:: I can do a workaround using read.xls from gdata instead of using read_excel from readxl. I'd like to figure out what the issue is for other though; read.xls is much slower than readxl.

```
setwd("/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Projects/MPB-LPP WBP Interactions/Summer 2017/WBP_LPP_GC/XLSFiles")

temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
myfiles <- base::lapply(temp, read_excel, skip=2)
temp.names <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(temp)
names(myfiles) <- temp.names

names.dfs <- c("Number", "Peak_Name", "RT", "Area", "Height", "Relative_Area", "Relative_Height", "Amount")

named.data=lapply(myfiles, setNames, names.dfs)

all.data <- rbindlist(named.data, use.names = TRUE, idcol = TRUE)
```

R version: 3.4.4, R Studio version: 1.1447, Computer, x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0

Packages loaded:

tidyverse, gdata, readxl, data.table

I also get the error message when I try reading in a small subset using:

```
small= sample(temp, 10)
myfiles=lapply(small, skip=2)
```

Comment: Hey Mike, which line throws the error? what is the error message?

Comment: I'm not getting any error message; but the line that crashes the session is: 

    myfiles=lapply(temp, read_excel, skip=2)

I've also tried using read_xls which also crashes the session.

Comment: ah sorry, missed that. Does `temp` look like what you'd expect?

Comment: temp is working as it is supposed to; its giving me the list of all the file names.

Comment: Maybe try printing the name in the loop, see if its one specific file or all of them e.g. 
base::lapply(temp, FUN = function(x){
  print(x)
  read_excel(x, skip=2)
}). Sorry don't know how to add new lines in comment

Comment: The session still aborts with that code.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest with `xls` format sorry. One option would be to convert to csv, which is more stable. e.g. library(rio);
convert("aa.xls", "aa.csv");
read.csv("aa.csv")